# How does one interact with the user from a vb.net service?

Tags: vb.net, forms, service, interaction

I've got one for you thats been bugging me for a bit.

If you run a Windows Service as Local System, how can that service display forms or prompts on the user desktop?

I tried this in one of my previous apps and couldn't get it to work; I settled on having an 'invisible' app running in the user context to handle any user interaction. But as time has passed, I've seen some apps that have nothing more than a service running as local system and yet they produce prompts and forms on the user desktop.

Thanks in advance for any info :)

Comment: This is totally contra to the design intent of a service. Why do you want your service to interact with your user?

Comment: *I've seen some apps that have nothing more than a service running as local system and yet they produce prompts and forms on the user desktop* - just because you can, doesn't mean you should